# Why does my develop branch make me commit a merge every time?

Tags: git, merge, pull

For some reason every time I do a `git pull` on my local develop branch it forces a new merge commit, creating a hideous monster in my PRs with many of these messages. How do I stop this?

`Merge branch 'develop' of github.com:repo into develop`

[image]

**update** with `git config -l file`

```html
credential.helper=osxkeychain
alias.last=log -1 HEAD
{more aliases}
user.name=xxx
user.email=xxx
pull.rebase=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.hookspath=.husky
remote.origin.url=xxx
xxx.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/ori
gin/*
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
{more branches}
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `git config -l` (make sure to redact all privacy related information).

Comment: this is added now

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have pull configured to merge, which is the default.

If you run `git fetch` instead if `git pull`, do you see updates on origin/develop? How would you like those updates integrated into your local develop branch?

The options are

1. merge (the default)
2. rebase (which re-applies your local changes on top of the remote ones)

You can't really use rebase if you've pushed your local develop branch to any remote (unless you want to force-push updates), but otherwise it's fine. Test it by running

```
git pull --rebase
```

explicitly, and set `pull.rebase` if you like this behaviour and want to make it the default.

---

NB. I'd always recommend running `fetch` first anyway, so you can check whether you actually want to integrate all the upstream changes immediately. Then again, if you develop on a feature branch instead of the shared `develop`, this really stops being such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling and pushing are all about sharing commits to make sure both sides have exactly the same set of commits.

When you pull, you will get a merge commit if:

- You have commits on this branch that the remote does not have.
- Or, the remote has commits on this branch that you do not have, and your `pull.ff` config (or perhaps `merge.ff`? I'm always a bit fuzzy on this) is set to `false`.

You can learn what the situation is by saying `git fetch` and then `git status`. Git will tell you who is behind and who is ahead. "Ahead" simply means "has commits that the other side does not".

If the remote is ahead and you are not, you can say `git pull --ff-only` to force a fast-forward and no merge commit.

Even if you are both ahead of and behind the remote, you can avoid the merge commit by saying `git pull --rebase`; this will pull down the commits from the remote that you do not have, and will then try to line up your commits that the remote does not have *after* those commits. But don't do that if you have already pushed this branch to form a pull request, as that would arguably constitute rewriting shared history, which is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the issue in this case was caused by putting a commit on top of the head and then merging new branches on top of it.

So the initial commit was never merged into develop (because i cant merge directly into develop), and the change was never noticed because the actual commit was merged in with a different branch.

rebase could have worked, but i find rebasing with 20 commits upstream to be a nightmare, so i just deleted the branch and re-pulled from origin.